# Searching MySQL Bin Log for a Query

Tags: mysql, binlog, mysqlbinlog

Is it possible to query the mysql bin log for a particular query? For example, suppose I want to know if anyone in the last hour did a specific query (like 'Update tableX where userName = 'bob'"). I just want to see if a particular query has been run recently.....

Comment: Actually, UPDATE isn't a query. SELECT is a query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use  mysqlbinlog - nix or mysqlbinlog.exe - windows

```
$bash>mysqlbinlog mysql_bin.log > mysql_bin.txt
```

After conversion You can search DML in mysql_bin.txt

Answer (score 5):

```
mysqlbinlog ${1} |grep -i  'update\|insert\|delete\|replace\|alter' | tr ‘[A-Z]’ ‘[a-z]’|sed -e '/*/d' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: Consider providing an explanation to the original post.  While the information may be a bit vague, your answer is a bit unclear.  Please explain to the OP why this will help

Comment: this command will return only queries that alter a value. further grepping could limit the results to a table name and even further to that same table with specific keywords. it may take a while to run, but would limit the results without disk usage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [MySQL general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) can help you.

Comment: Actually I already read that and only saw options for things like search by start and end time. I was hoping to avoid writing the entire multi-gigabyte bin log to disk and then having to grep it.

Answer (score 0):

The upvoted answer did't help me. The reason is that `mysqlbinlog` uses [BINLOG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binlog.html) statement which is readable by server and it can't be used to filter queries.

But fortunately there's the `-v` [option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_version) which reconstructs the query and allows to make searches. This option applies both to MySQL 5.7 and 8.

Use this command to check if *mytable* was updated:

```
mysqldump -v mysql-bin.log | grep UPDATE | grep mytable
```